# How to ignore all other database parameters when retrieving one database parameter

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, parameters

I created a simple code that retrieves a database parameter which is ("SOPNUMBE", ordernumber)
However, sometimes an employee will fill out an incorrect order giving me a "LIFTxxxx" value instead of a SOPNUMBE which is "ORDxxxxx" etc. Since L is before S, my ftp site processes LIFT first creating an error. I would really like to have this application ignore everything besides "SOPNUMBE", I feel this is a pretty simple question and to me it sounds like a simple if then statement. But I am having trouble wording it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

```
public bool UpdateOrderToShipped(string order)
{
    orderNumber = order;
    string batch = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SuccessfulOrderBatch"];
    string statement = "UPDATE SOP10100 SET BACHNUMB = '"+ batch +"' WHERE SOPNUMBE = @SOPNUMBE";
    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(statement, connectionPCI);
    comm.Parameters.Add("SOPNUMBE", orderNumber);
    try
    {
        comm.Connection.Open();
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        comm.Connection.Close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        comm.Connection.Close();
        KaplanFTP.errorMsg = "Database error: " + e.Message;
    }
    statement = "SELECT SOPTYPE FROM SOP10100 WHERE SOPNUMBE = @SOPNUMBE";
    comm.CommandText = statement;
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    soptype = dt.Rows[0]["SOPTYPE"].ToString();



    return true;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but your question is pretty hard to understand. What does the FTP site and alphabetical order have to do with this code? Do you just want to add code to this that checks the first characters of the [order] parameter?

Comment: Yes, Im sorry I am pretty new at this. Adding code to check the first characters of the [order] parameter is exactly what I want to do.

Comment: Why are you not validating the data when the user first inputs it? You shouldn't be calling the methods that writes an order number to the database if the order number is invalid.

Comment: So in English "If the first three characters are "ORD" then do this, but otherwise do [???]" What should this do in if that's not the case? If you aren't comfortable with if statements, then you probably shouldn't be working in this code. Chances are high that you'll break something else.

Comment: If the first three characters are ORD, then store the data, if its not, then ignore.

Comment: But this function is required to return something: you'll have to return true or false. Please see my changes to my earlier comment. (Also, should add these changes to the original question.) I'll provide an answer, but I have a bad feeling about your familiarity with coding.

Comment: You are correct to say my coding is at the naive level. This is why I am reaching out to a community for help. I was actually referred to this community by a programmer who is much more advanced than I. I understand I require an if statement, but since the code requires I return a value, I am having trouble coding this. This is not a live website, this is just a side project I have been working on. I do not think I will break anything, how you become a good programmer is trial and error right? :D I will modify my question though to make more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LAs noted in my comment, if you aren't comfortable changing this code with an if statement, then you probably shouldn't be maintaining this code. (Do you know where else this code is referenced? Your change will be affecting those places.)

But here you go...

```
public bool UpdateOrderToShipped(string order)
{
    if ((String.CompareOrdinal(order, 0, "ORD", 0, 3) == 0)
    {
       orderNumber = order;
       string batch = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SuccessfulOrderBatch"];
       string statement = "UPDATE SOP10100 SET BACHNUMB = '"+ batch +"' WHERE SOPNUMBE = @SOPNUMBE";
       SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(statement, connectionPCI);
       comm.Parameters.Add("SOPNUMBE", orderNumber);
       try
       {
           comm.Connection.Open();
           comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
           comm.Connection.Close();
       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
           comm.Connection.Close();
           KaplanFTP.errorMsg = "Database error: " + e.Message;
       }
       statement = "SELECT SOPTYPE FROM SOP10100 WHERE SOPNUMBE = @SOPNUMBE";
       comm.CommandText = statement;
       SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
       DataTable dt = new DataTable();
       da.Fill(dt);
       soptype = dt.Rows[0]["SOPTYPE"].ToString();



       return true;
   } else
   {
      return false;
   }
 }
```

Comment: As far as I know, this code is not referenced anywhere else. Thank you for your help, I will continue experimenting.

Comment: That can throw a `NullReferenceException` if the order string is null. Another way to write the if statement is `if (String.CompareOrdinal(order, 0, "ORD", 0, 3) == 0 && order.Length > 3)`. This prevents the exception because the `Length` property will only be accessed if the first three letters of order are 'ORD'.

Comment: @ Joshua @ Jamie F, what if I wanted to say "All except LIFT" instead of "Only ORD", would it then be 

        (String.CompareOrdinal(order, 0, "LIFT", 0, 4) != 0) ?

Comment: Yes. That will do what you describe. Keep in mind these comparisons are case sensitive. "Lift" or "lift" would be processed in this case.

Comment: Jamie F, I just got done reading your ego-infested post in another blog about this current post. I couldnt help but laugh at the stereotype expert who feels too proud to answer a newb question. This code is just for fun. If you dont wish to answer newb questions then dont. This is my first question on this blog and I even apologized for the bad wording. The ironic and funny thing about it was your first if statement was incorrect, even when Joshua corrected you, you still didnt double close the paras ))*. If youre going to be insulting and rude, at least dont be sloppy.

Comment: Sorry you took offense: I purposely did not link to this question (someone edited to add the link.) "Ego-infested"? Despite the warnings of others, I helped you. I gave you the benefit of the doubt, and I helped you again today (for no points). Take a look at your original question: it's much worse than what I shared: "My ftp site processes L before S, so how should my code handle a SOPNUMBE that isn't a SOPNUMBE." I stand by my statements: I don't think you should be editing this code for production: you only made it clear this is a hobby project recently.

Comment: @JamieF - It appears that the OP definitively answered your question about whether or not you should have tried to help him/her:  clearly, you shouldn't have.  Oh well, live and learn.